# Chrome Download Permissions

Tags: permissions, google-chrome

When I download a file to my Downloads folder through Chrome, the default permissions are `-rw-r-----`.

I'd like my downloads to automatically permit `-rw-rw-rw-`.

Is there an easy way to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that chromium isn't honoring the system's [umask](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html).  [This](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409416) issue has been tracking the problem.  [This](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/8a24d2b903636c83780281400aeba6164fdb358a) commit is referenced in that issue and claims to have fixed the problem, but as of version 47.0.2526.73 (current stable version at the time of this writing) the problem persists.

Comment: Well, that's frustrating.